# Calculating Hamming distance for two vectors in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying just to calculate the Hamming distance between two vectors in R. I'm currently attempting to use the "e1071" package, and the hamming.distance function, as follows:

```
library(e1071)
H <- hamming.distance(X)
```

Where X is a data.frame with 2 rows and (in my particular data) 667 columns, and every observation is 0 or 1.

Initially I got the error:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

After some research, it appeared that one fix might be increasing the basic option in R. This I did via options(expressions=5000), and then tried varying values in place of the 5000. But this only produced the error:

```
Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit
```

I'm not much of a programmer, and the fixes for this most recent error appear to have to do with something inside the package e1071 possibly not being called correctly (or at the right time).

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I eventually want the Hamming distances between a large number of vectors, and this was just a starting point. If this has to do with memory allocation, any suggestions for how to deal with it?

Comment: It is not really a memory problem, but a stack problem: the function is recursive, and calls itself as many times as you have columns. You may want to check if there are other, non-recursive implementations (e.g., by typing `library(sos); ???hamming`), or implement your own. In addition, I cannot reproduce the problem (`expressions` is already 5000 for me): information about your platform (e.g., `sessionInfo()`) may be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know how `hamming.distance` works internally, but a simple way to calculate the distance for 2 vectors is just

```
sum(x1 != x2)
```

or, in this case,

```
sum(X[1,] != X[2,])
```

If the total number of vectors is not too large (up to, say, a few thousand), you could implement this in a nested loop:

```
n <- nrow(X)
m <- matrix(nrow=n, ncol=n)
for(i in seq_len(n - 1))
    for(j in seq(i, n))
        m[j, i] <- m[i, j] <- sum(X[i,] != X[j,])
```

Caveat: untested.

Comment: Fantastic! You guys are a huge help. This is awesome.

Comment: Be careful about NA testing.

Answer (score 9):

WARNING ABOUT USING HAMMING.DISTANCE FROM PACKAGE e1071!

This package's implementation forces the objects being compared to booleans with as.logical. This means that values of 0 will be FALSE and any non-zero values will be TRUE. This means that for the sequence: 0 1 2 compared to 0 1 1 the hamming distance will be reported as 0 instead of the correct value of 1 -- this package will treat 1 and 2 as equal since as.logical(1) == as.logical(2).

Here is the faulty (in my view) implementation:

```
    > library("e1071", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library")
    Loading required package: class
    > hamming.distance
    function (x, y) 
    {
        z <- NULL
        if (is.vector(x) && is.vector(y)) {
            z <- sum(as.logical(x) != as.logical(y))
        }
        else {
            z <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(x), ncol = nrow(x))
            for (k in 1:(nrow(x) - 1)) {
                for (l in (k + 1):nrow(x)) {
                    z[k, l] <- hamming.distance(x[k, ], x[l, ])
                    z[l, k] <- z[k, l]
                }
            }
            dimnames(z) <- list(dimnames(x)[[1]], dimnames(x)[[1]])
        }
        z
    }
    <environment: namespace:e1071>
```

My recommendation: DO NOT USE. Hamming distance is trivial to implement as noted several times above.

Comment: Thanks for the note on this. I did end up just calculating it using the really simple method noted by Hong Ooi. But this is good to know in general.

Comment: I went ahead and shot an email to the package maintainer about this issue.

Answer (score 7):

`hamming.distance` takes *two* vectors or a matrix, but not a data frame, so what you want is probably either

```
m = as.matrix(X)
hamming.distance(m[1,], m[2,])
```

or

```
hamming.distance(as.matrix(X))
```

but as was pointed out this is in your particular case the same as

```
sum(m[1,] != m[2,])
```

(In general, avoid `data.frame`s if what you have is not a heterogenous structure since they are much, much slower than matrices)

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to all that was mentioned above: Although the Hamming distance is trivial to implement as an ordinary nested loop, in terms of execution time things can quickly get out of hand for larger matrices. In R, it is far more efficient to instead use matrix multiplication for computing the Hamming distance between all columns of large matrices. This is extremely fast compared to an R-level nested loop. An example implementation can be found [here](https://johanndejong.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/faster-hamming-distance-in-r-2/).

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(xor(x[1,],x[2,]))
```

I don't know the relative efficiency of 'xor' to '!='

Comment: `xor` is implemented as `function (x, y) { (x | y) & !(x & y) }` while `!=` is a Primitive function. I suspect `!=` is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to *@HongOoi* I want to point that in R `!=` and `==` return `NA` when one of the values is missing, so it could give misleading results

```
> c(1, NA) == 1:2
[1] TRUE   NA
```

however `%in%` outputs `FALSE` for `1 %in% NA` comparison. Because of that if when comparing vectors you want to count missing values as "different", then you have to use `sum(!((x != y) %in% FALSE))` code:

```
> x <- c(1, 8, 5, NA, 5)
> y <- 1:5
> sum(!((x != y) %in% FALSE))
[1] 3
```

Notice also that it could happen that `x` and `y` vectors have different length, what would lead to missing values in the shorter vector - you can do two things: truncate the longer vector or claim that values absent in the shorter vector are "different". This could be translated into standalone function with familiar R parameters:

```
hamming <- function(x, y, na.rm = TRUE) {
  size <- 1:max(length(x) & length(y))
  x <- x[size]
  y <- y[size]
  if (na.rm) {
    del <- is.na(x) & is.na(y)
    x <- x[del]
    y <- y[del]
  }
  sum(!((x != y) %in% FALSE))
}
```

This function enables you to choose if you want to count missing values as "different" (`na.rm = FALSE`) or ignore them. With `na.rm = TRUE` if vectors differ in their length, the longer one gets truncated.