# Mixed types when reading csv files. Causes, fixes and consequences

Tags: python, csv, pandas

What exactly happens when Pandas issues this warning? Should I worry about it?

```
In [1]: read_csv(path_to_my_file)
/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py:1139: 
DtypeWarning: Columns (4,13,29,51,56,57,58,63,87,96) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.              

  data = self._reader.read(nrows)
```

I assume that this means that Pandas is unable to infer the type from values on those columns. But if that is the case, **what type does Pandas end up using for those columns**?

Also, can the type always be recovered after the fact? (after getting the warning), or are there cases where I may not be able to recover the original info correctly, and I should pre-specify the type?

Finally, how exactly does `low_memory=False` fix the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Revisiting mbatchkarov's link, `low_memory` is [not deprecated](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5888).
It is [now documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **low_memory** : *boolean, default True*
>
> Internally process the file in chunks, resulting in lower memory use while
>   parsing, but possibly mixed type inference. To ensure no
>   mixed types either set False, or specify the type with the *dtype*
>   parameter. Note that the entire file is read into a single DataFrame
>   regardless, use the *chunksize* or *iterator* parameter to return the data
>   in chunks. (Only valid with C parser)

[I have asked](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13293#pullrequestreview-8216118) what *resulting in mixed type inference* means, and chris-b1 answered:

> It is deterministic - types are consistently inferred based on what's
>   in the data. That said, the internal chunksize is not a fixed number
>   of rows, but instead bytes, so whether you can a mixed dtype warning
>   or not can feel a bit random.

So, **what type does Pandas end up using for those columns?**

This is answered by the following self-contained example:

```
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join([str(x) for x in range(1000000)] + ['a string'])))
DtypeWarning: Columns (0) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.

type(df.loc[524287,'0'])
Out[50]: int

type(df.loc[524288,'0'])
Out[51]: str
```

The first part of the csv data was seen as only int, so converted to int,
the second part also had a string, so all entries were kept as string.

**Can the type always be recovered after the fact? (after getting the warning)?**

I guess re-exporting to csv and re-reading with `low_memory=False` should do the job.

**How exactly does low_memory=False fix the problem?**

It reads all of the file before deciding the type, therefore needing more memory.

Comment: I first got the DType warning, which goes away after I use low_memory=False.
However, there's this error `Error: C stack usage  528430048 is too close to the limit
Error: C stack usage  528429312 is too close to the limit`. This had been there even before the low_memory=False flag. Any fix for this?
I changed the R version as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit), it worked just once, but I get the error consistently now.

Answer (score 7):

`low_memory` is apparently [kind of deprecated](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5888), so I wouldn't bother with it.

The warning means that some of the values in a column have one dtype (e.g. `str`), and some have a different dtype (e.g. `float`). I believe pandas uses the lowest common super type, which in the example I used would be `object`.

You should check your data, or post some of it here. In particular, look for missing values or inconsistently formatted `int`/`float` values. If you are certain your data is correct, then use the `dtypes` parameter to help `pandas` out.

Comment: low_memory is not deprecated,as @Robert Pollak answered.