# How to find the input line with mixed types

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a large csv in pandas with:

```
features = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, names=['Time','Duration','SrcDevice','DstDevice','Protocol','SrcPort','DstPort','SrcPackets','DstPackets','SrcBytes','DstBytes'], usecols=['Duration','SrcDevice', 'DstDevice', 'Protocol', 'DstPort','SrcPackets','DstPackets','SrcBytes','DstBytes'])
```

I get:

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (6) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  %!PS-Adobe-3.0
```

How can I find the first line in the input which is causing this warning? I need to do this to debug the problem with the input file, which shouldn't have mixed types.

Comment: please see similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251219/pandas-read-csv-low-memory-and-dtype-options

Comment: @mm441 Thank you but that doesn't seem to contain an answer to how to find the line that causes the warning does it?

Comment: How big is your file? If it's small enough, "by eye" may be the fastest way.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  About 4 millions lines.

Comment: Have an intern do it then :)

Answer (score 2):

Once Pandas has finished reading the file, you can **NOT** figure out which lines were problematic (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40585000/9094710) to know why).

This means you should find a way **while** you are reading the file. For example, read the file line-by-line, and check the types of each line, if any of them doesn't match the expected type then you got the wanted line.

To achieve this with Pandas, you can pass `chunksize=1` to `pd.read_csv()` to read the file in chunks (dataframes with size N, 1 in this case). See the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) if you want to know more about this.

The code goes something like this:

```
# read the file in chunks of size 1. This returns a reader rather than a DataFrame
reader = pd.read_csv(filename,chunksize=1)

# get the first chunk (DataFrame), to calculate the "true" expected types
first_row_df = reader.get_chunk()
expected_types = [type(val) for val in first_row_df.iloc[0]] # a list of the expected types.

i = 1 # the current index. Start from 1 because we've already read the first row.
for row_df in reader:
    row_types = [type(val) for val in row_df.iloc[0]]
    if row_types != expected_types:
        print(i) # this row is the wanted one
        break
    i += 1
```

Note that this code makes an assumption that the first row has "true" types.
This code is really slow, so I recommend that you actually only check the columns which you think are problematic (though this does not give much performance gain).

Answer (score 1):

```
for endrow in range(1000, 4000000, 1000):
    startrow = endrow - 1000
    rows = 1000
    try:
        pd.read_csv(filename, dtype={"DstPort": int}, skiprows=startrow, nrows=rows, header=None,
                names=['Time','Duration','SrcDevice','DstDevice','Protocol','SrcPort',
                       'DstPort','SrcPackets','DstPackets','SrcBytes','DstBytes'],
                usecols=['Duration','SrcDevice', 'DstDevice', 'Protocol', 'DstPort',
                         'SrcPackets','DstPackets','SrcBytes','DstBytes'])
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Error is from row {startrow} to row {endrows}")
```

Split the file into multiple dataframes with 1000 rows each to see in which range of rows there is mixed type value that causes this problem.