# Should I ignore DtypeWarning: Columns(17,62).....?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this type of error when reading a csv file. What does this error tell me? Should I ignore it?

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (17,62) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
```

Comment: Mixed type means your column data is being parsed as more than one type; e.g. some may be read as an `int` and some as a `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that there are mixed data types, it is not clear what is specifically causing the issue. Can you post the full error message? Some options are:

1. Try passing `, dtype='unicode'` or another dtype when you `pd.read_csv`(). That's what one user said here: https://github.com/oSoc19/best/issues/87.
2. You can also get rid of the error by doing what it is telling you to do. Pass `,low_memory=False`.

Per the accepted solution in this post: [Mixed types when reading csv files. Causes, fixes and consequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488675/mixed-types-when-reading-csv-files-causes-fixes-and-consequences)

*"How exactly does low_memory=False fix the problem?
**It reads all of the file before deciding the type, therefore needing more memory**."*