# Allowed Memory in R and C Stack Usage

Tags: r, memory, stack

I'm trying to read in a large file (~5GB) into R and process the data. I can successfully read in the entire 5GB file, but the trouble comes when I apply my processing. I don't have a great grasp on memory basics in R, and I'm hoping some of you can help me understand better.

Here is an example of what I'm running

```
file = fread("file.txt") #file.txt is 5GB of unprocessed data
t.str <-strptime(file$time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"")#convert column to date class
month = as.numeric(format(t.str, "%m"))#create vector from file column
high = ifelse(file$age>70,1,0) #create vector from file column
#There are about ten more lines that operate on this file.
```

fread does a fine job of reading in the file. And the first three or four operations that I run on the 'file' data frame work. However, after a certain number of them run, I get an error that says:

```
C stack usage 19923892 is too close to the limit
```

I'm pretty sure the issue isn't a certain command I'm running since it worked on smaller data sets. I've read a bit on what stacks are, but this warning isn't totally making sense to me. Does this mean that R is using a pointer to run through these big vectors, and I've run out of pointer space (?). I read about a similar issue here:

[Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit)

One user suggested increasing the stack size in the shell. I tried looking in to this further, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Here is what they suggested:

```
$ ulimit -s # print default
8192
$ R --slave -e 'Cstack_info()["size"]'
size 
8388608
```

Can anyone help me understand what this means, or just explain a bit about stack usage in R? Or does anyone know of a better way to process this data that doesn't exceed the stack usage? I'm not sure how to give you guys reproducible data.

Edit to add in example of data:

```
PersonID     time              Energy   Age
1301839    07/24/2013 07:15:00  0.13    68
1301521    07/24/2013 07:30:00  0.19    68
1301890    07/24/2013 07:45:00  0.10    68
1301890    07/24/2013 08:00:00  0.06    68
1307112    07/24/2013 08:15:00  0.01    68
```

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the data file?  For starters, Simon's [fasttime](http://rforge.net/fasttime) will beat `strptime` etc pp

Comment: Data example added. This package looks like it's faster, thanks. Does it deal with stacks differently?

Comment: Ok, non-standard date format so you will have to parse it via `strptime`. Also your format string is `%Y-%d-%d`, but needs to be `%m/%d/%Y` (followed by `%H:%M:%S` as you have).

Comment: Ah right, It's correct in my original code, I'll edit the correct format in

Comment: The answer in the reference questions provide how you can change the limit to 16384 KB. `ulimit -s 16384 # enlarge stack limit to 16 megs`  It's in the next box after the one you quoted.  That's how to change.  From the error you got, try something larger than 19,924 KB.  Sorry, I can't really answer your request to understand what it means.

Comment: I know this is very basic, but in what shell do I enter that command? Where do I have to located? I tried in the bash shell, but that didn't work. I think I'm going to spend some time learning bash commands because it seems useful. Thanks for the answer and the clarification, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this really isn't an answer, but I don't have enough points to comment. You could try reading and processing the data in chunks, or check out some of the large memory packages in the CRAN Task View [High Performance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) . You can also read about memory usage [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html).

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Once I have chunks that are small enough, it works, and it's not that slow. Thanks for the reference to High Performance Computing, I'll definitely check it out.