# Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit in R

Tags: r, shell, stack

I am trying to apply the following code:

```
library(FinancialInstrument)
stock(TLT, currency="USD", multiplier=1)
```

But I receive the following Error: **C stack usage  19924192 is too close to the limit**

This problem were discussed previously and the best answer suggested to use `ulimit` command.

[Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit)

Can someone please elaborate on how to do it step by step or if there is any other solutions for this problem?

Comment: I have this error too. Did you fix it ?if u fix it, would you mind provide the answer on here? thank you.