# simplify lists recursively using unlist

Tags: r, list, purrr, simplify

Consider a case like this:

```
xml_list <- list(
  a = "7",
  b = list("8"),
  c = list(
    c.a = "7",
    c.b = list("8"), 
    c.c = list("9", "10"),
    c.d = c("11", "12", "13")),
  d = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

what I'm looking for is a way of how to simplify this construct recursively such that `unlist` is called on any `list` of length 1. The expected result for above example would look like:

```
list(
  a = "7",
  b = "8",
  c = list(
    c.a = "7",
    c.b = "8", 
    c.c = list("9", "10"),
    c.d = c("11", "12", "13")),
 d = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

I have dabbled with `rapply`, but that explicitly operates on `list`-members that are **NOT** lists themselves, so wrote the following:

```
library(magrittr)
clean_up_list <- function(xml_list){
  xml_list %>%
    lapply(
      function(x){
        if(is.list(x)){
          if(length(x) == 1){
            x %<>%
              unlist()
          } else {
            x %<>%
              clean_up_list()
          }
        }
        return(x)
      })
}
```

This, however, I can't even test, as `Error: C stack usage  7969588 is too close to the limit` (at least on lists that I terminally want to process).

Digging deeper (and after mulling over @Roland's response), I came up with a solution that utilizes `purrr`-goodness, reversely iterates over list depth and **NEARLY** does what I want:

```
clean_up_list <- function(xml_list)
{
  list_depth <- xml_list %>%
    purrr::vec_depth()
  for(dl in rev(sequence(list_depth)))
  {
    xml_list %<>%
      purrr::modify_depth(
        .depth = dl,
        .ragged = TRUE,
        .f = function(x)
        {
          if(is.list(x) && length(x) == 1 && length(x[[1]]) == 1)
          {
            unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)
          } else {
            x
          }
        })
  }
  return(xml_list)
}
```

This appears to work as intended even for lists of the depth I'm dealing with **BUT** elements that used to be vectors (like `c.d` and `d` in the example) now are converted to `lists`, which defeats the purpose ... any further insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a [ticket](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/601#issue-389733933) against the `github` repository of `purrr` I solved this: with the current developer's version of `purrr` (installable via `remotes::install_github('tidyverse/purrr')`), the `purrr`-dpendent code in the question works as expected and does not any longer "listify" vectors. That code thus should serve as the answer to the question and become fully functional with `CRAN`-borne packages after the new year 2018/19.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this magrittr stuff, but it's easy to create a recursive function:

```
foo <- function(L) lapply(L, function(x) {
  if (is.list(x) && length(x) > 1) return(foo(x))
  if (is.list(x) && length(x) == 1) x[[1]] else x
  })
foo(test_list)

#$`a`
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
#
#$b
#[1] "a"
#
#$c
#$c$`c.1`
#[1] "b"
#
#$c$c.2
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
#
#$c$c.3
#$c$c.3[[1]]
#[1] "c"
#
#$c$c.3[[2]]
#[1] "d"
```

If this throws an error regarding C stack usuage then you have lists that are deeply nested. You couldn't use recursion then, which would make this a challenging problem. I would then modify the creation of this list if possible. Or you could then try to [increase the C stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181989/how-to-set-the-size-of-the-c-stack-in-r).

Comment: Thanks. This does in essence what my own function attempts and fails with the same C stack problem in a real (deeper) list.

Comment: See the last part of my answer. I think you might have an xy problem.