# Sparklyr: How to attach a group by to invoke method?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparkr, sparklyr

I have this Spark table:

```
xydata
y: num 11.00 22.00 33.00 ...
x0: num 1.00 2.00 3.00 ...
x1: num 2.00 3.00 4.00 ...
...
x788: num 2.00 3.00 4.00 ...
```

and a handle named `xy_df` that is connected to this table.

I want to `invoke` the `selectExpr` function to calculate the `mean`, something like:

```
xy_centered <- xy_df %>%  
    spark_dataframe() %>% 
    invoke("selectExpr", list("( y0-mean(y0) ) AS y0mean"))
```

which is also applicable to all other columns.

But when I run it, it gives this error:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'y0' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

I know this happens because, in common SQL rules, I didn't put a `GROUP BY` clause for columns contained in the aggregate function (`mean`). How do I put the `GROUP BY` to the `invoke` method?

Previously, I manage to do complete the purpose using another way, which is by:

1. Calculate the `mean` of each column by `summarize_all`
2. Collect the `mean` inside R
3. Apply this mean using `invoke` and `selectExpr`

[as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43614889/7913448), but now I'm trying to speed up the execution time a bit by putting all operation inside the Spark itself, without retrieving anything to R.

My Spark version is 1.6.0

Comment: Could you try this? `xy_centered <- xy_df %>% spark_dataframe() %>% invoke("group_by", list("y0")) %>% invoke("selectExpr", list("( y0-mean(y0) ) AS y0mean"))`

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel it gave this error `Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid method group_by for object 157`. Does `group_by` also covered by `invoke`? I don't really understand what are the methods that can be used with `invoke`, are they only `Scala` methods?