# Reformatting an R's data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, magrittr

I have a `data.frame` of this format:

```
set.seed(1)
pl.mat <-matrix(rnorm(500*1000),nrow=500,ncol=1000)
colnames(pl.mat) <- gsub("\\s+","",apply(expand.grid(paste("pl",1:10,sep=""),1:100),1,function(x) paste(unlist(x),collapse=".")),perl=T)
df <- cbind(data.frame(id=1:500,group.id=rep(1:25,20)),pl.mat)

> df[1:5,1:5]
  id group.id      pl1.1       pl2.1       pl3.1
1  1        1 -0.6264538  0.07730312  1.13496509
2  2        2  0.1836433 -0.29686864  1.11193185
3  3        3 -0.8356286 -1.18324224 -0.87077763
4  4        4  1.5952808  0.01129269  0.21073159
5  5        5  0.3295078  0.99160104  0.06939565
```

`df$id` are grouped by `df$group.id`. Then each column has an experimental plate id (`pl1`-`pl10`), and the integer following the period separator is a well id (1-100). Hence each plate has 100 columns.

I want to build a new `data.frame` which these columns:
`df$id`, `df$group.id`, well id, and the all plates.

Meaning this format:

```
id group.id      well.id      pl1       pl2       pl3
1  1             1     -0.6264538 0.07730312  1.13496509
1  1             2            ...       ...       ...
.
.
.
1  2             1            ...       ...       ...
.
.
.
500 25 .        100           ...       ...       ...
```

Any good concise code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  gather(var, val, -id, -group.id) %>%
  separate(var, c("pl.id", "well.id")) %>% 
  spread(pl.id, val)
```

Comment: For my real data I'm getting: Error: C stack usage  135438240 is too close to the limit. Is this due to a recursion that one of these functions is applying? If so, is there a non-recursive alternative?

Comment: Suspect your data-set is too big to produce that error. There's some discussion of [Error: C stack usage is too close to limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit). See if you can break your data up into smaller sections first. Also, you could try `reshape2::melt` and `dcast` instead of gather and spread.

Answer (score 1):

Dan, you could create a new `data.frame` with the desired columns. Let's say you want column `df$id` and `df$group.id`:

`newDF <- as.data.frame(cbind(df$id, df$group.id))`

Now, if you had such a huge amount of columns where you cannot write-out any, you could use the index as well:

`newDF <- as.data.frame(cbind(df[,2], df[,5]))`

Therefore, also ranges work:

`newDF <- as.data.frame(cbind(df[,2:210], df[,507:1020]))`

Does this work for you? Another solution would be to use a loop and construct the indices or column names dynamically. Here a draft:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  print(eval(parse(text=paste("df$id", i, sep = ""))))
}
```

Here, the column names `df$id1` up to `df$id10` gets build dynamically.

Best regards, Thorsten