# Django - App crashing when using pandas2ri

Tags: python, r, django, pandas, rpy2

I am implementing rpy2 code in Django and when I convert pandas dataframe into r dataframe my app starts crashing and giving error:

```
Error: C stack usage  60820464 is too close to the limit
```

otherwise app works fine as long as i don't convert. Is there any problem/mistake in my code?

My code snippet:

```
from .models import Values
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

def rpyset(request):
filterdata = pd.DataFrame(list(Values.objects.all().values('val1','val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6')))
r_dataframe = pandas2ri.py2ri(filterdata)
# I want to pass r_dataframe to an rpy2 function but unable to proceed because of error
return HttpResponse(filterdataahp.to_html())
```

Comment: Maybe your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14719448/8258902

Comment: It's not the Windows fix, does ulimit has a replacement in Windows?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/133122/ulimit-for-windows

Comment: could'nt find the solution from this. Thank you for the response