# Is there a way to prevent RStudio from resetting the memory limit on my local machine?

Tags: r, rstudio

When launching RStudio with a fresh environment, I enable to `googlesheets` library and then attempt to list available sheets with `gs_ls()`.  I get the error:

I have tried [resetting the ulimit in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit) and then relaunching, but RStudio keeps resetting it in the virtual environment, but to no avail.  As soon as I launch RStudio, the ulimit reverts.  I also do not have a large amount of Google Sheets to query in my Google Drive directory. Any ideas?

```
> library(googlesheets)
> gs_ls()
Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
Error: C stack usage  7970576 is too close to the limit
```

At this point, I should expect to see a list of available Google Sheets workbooks that I can select from and can then import the data.  If I know the Sheet's name and I can see it in my Google Drive Home directory, I can simply copy the workbook title and the use the gs_title command to assign the variable and then import.  But this is incredibly inefficient and not a programmatic or scalable option.