# augment stack dimension on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, stack

I'm working on a shiny server and I'm doing some quite complex operations. 
The problem I've found is that, after some minutes working on large data frames, the app crashed with this error: 
`Error: C stack usage  7969194 is too close to the limit. Execution halted.`
I googled it and I've found that from the cmd in ubuntu with this command `ulimit -s 16384` you can augment the stack size but I didn't find how to do it in the shiny server.

Please, does someone have some ideas?

Thank you

Comment: I have exactly the same problem: I do not seem to be able to tell the shiny server to run the system R with setting the ulimit differently. Does it work if you set the ulimit internally, with a system command or with ulimit::memory_limit(2000)?

Comment: I bet this has more to do with a logic error in a function that's triggering some sort of infinite recursion. Changing the ulimit probably won't help much. But it's hard to tell without a proper minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Have you tested and verified all your functions outside the shiny environment first?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

Add the following lines to the end of `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
* soft memlock unlimited
* hard memlock unlimited

* soft stack unlimited
* hard stack unlimited
```

Credited to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65019901/3522482). Bascially this change will adjust the size of stack and memlock memories to unlimited.

**More Background:**

As OP points out, one can use [`ulimit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14719448/3522482) to adjust available stack size before entering an R session.

The R package [`rlimit`](https://rdrr.io/cran/unix/man/rlimit.html) is supposed to work just like the command line utility `ulimit`, however, I cannot produce the same behavior after entering into an R session:

```
Cstack_info()["size"] # prints 7969177
rlimit_stack(16384, 16384) # expect 16777216
Cstack_info()["size"] # still prints 7969177
```

Eventually I found the above TLDR solution and `Error: C stack usage 7969194 is too close to the limit. Execution halted.` goes away.