# How to deal with C stack usage error in R

Tags: r, svm

I running the below SVM code in R

```
model<-ksvm(data$size_category~.,data=data_training,kernel="stringdot").
```

But I am getting the error `C stack usage  15924720 is too close to the limit`.I am not able to figure out why this error is happening.

Comment: Hi Bet. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit). Maybe this will help you. This error message occours when your ressources are depleted