# "Error: C stack usage 15925652 is too close to the limit" when View() dataset in R

Tags: r

When I run the command:

> View(ds)

I get:

"Error: C stack usage  15925652 is too close to the limit"

What is the likely cause? How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: What type of object is `ds`? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You might want to check this topic :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit