# Performance of Distance calculation between categoial vectors in R

Tags: performance, r, categories, distance

i am calculating the distance between two categorical vectors (i.e. character vectors) as follows:

```
Distanz <- function(Ref,Inp){
  y <- numeric(length=1)
  for(i in 1:length(Ref)){
    if(Ref[i] != Inp[i]){y <- y+1}
  }
  return(y)
}
```

Obviously the vectors have the same length. The result is the number of dimensions in which the two vectors differ.

But i am having performance problems. Does anyone have an idea how to fasten this calculation?

Thanks,
Lukas

Comment: done - i am using y<-sum(Ref != Inp). Please excuse my question - i am just getting warm with R...

Comment: Rumour has it vectorizing it often makes it quicker - I'm new to this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what size of vectors you are dealing with, or what too slow means, but this is just the [hamming distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997198/calculating-hamming-distance-for-two-vectors-in-r), right? Does this work

```
sum(Ref != Inp)
```