# calculate pairwise Hamming distance and retain smaller one

Tags: r

I have a matrix:

```
A = matrix( c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
dimnames(A) = list(c("Taxa1", "Taxa2", "Taxa3"), c("A1", "B1", "C1"))
df <- data.frame("ID" = c("A1", "B1", "C1"), "Triplicate" = c("T1", "T1", "T1"))
```

I would like to calculate the Hamming distance between A1 and B1, and between A1 and C1 for one taxa and retain the minimum of the two as the designated value for A1. Then calculate the Hamming distance between B1 and A1 (which we already did) and B1 and C1 and retain the minimum of that value for B1 and so on for C1. Note samples A1, B1, C1 are part of the same Triplicate indicated by T1. I will have similar other `Triplicate` samples `T2, T3 or T4` and I would like to group samples based on the `Triplicate` column value for calculating pairwise Hamming

Resulting matrix would be:

```
df$Hamming <- c(2, 2, 2)
```

As distance between A1, B1 and A1, C1 is 2 so retaining the value as 2.

PS: Simple 1 min description of Hamming distance:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P02mJhS9qQ4

Adding exact data I am working with:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrlwmdipeyhbcok/Hamming.RData?dl=0

Comment: Do you want the distance between A1 and resp. B1 and C1 for each taxum, or is it for all taxa? Could you maybe include your expected result?

Comment: the values in the matrix represents binary or decimal numbers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997198/calculating-hamming-distance-for-two-vectors-in-r

Comment: @Lamia added the result. I would like the distance summed over all taxa. Let me know if you have any questions

@Sathish the matrix could be binary if that helps. That link you shared does not group the answer as I would like with my `triplicate` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit flip is identified by using `xor()` function, and the total number of bit flips is found by summing the results from `xor()` function. I did not optimize the code in `hamm_dist_min()`.

```
xor(0,0)
# [1] FALSE
xor(1,1)
# [1] FALSE
xor(0,1)
# [1] TRUE
xor(1,0)
# [1] TRUE
```

As per OP's requirement, the hamming distance is computed for both directions. For example: AB, BA, AC, CA, BC, and CB which forms triplicates as ABC, BCA, and CAB. If you want only one direction, for example: AB, AC, and BC you can use `combn()` function to setup the column numbers inside the `hamm_dist_min()` function.

Data:

```
A = matrix( c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
dimnames(A) = list(c("Taxa1", "Taxa2", "Taxa3"), c("A1", "B1", "C1"))
df <- data.frame("ID" = c("A1", "B1", "C1"), "Triplicate" = c("T1", "T1", "T1"))
```

Hamming Distance

```
# minimum of hamming distance
hamm_dist_min <- function(data)
{
  # setup combinations of column numbers
  n_col <- ncol(data)
  x <- expand.grid(seq_len(n_col), seq_len(n_col))
  x <- x[ x[, 1] != x[, 2], ]
  x <- x[order(x[, 1]), ]
  x <- split(x, cut(x[, 1], breaks = c(0, seq_len(n_col)), labels = colnames(data) ))

  # minimum of hamming distance
  h_d <- unlist(lapply(x, function(y){
    min( colSums(apply(y, 1, function(z) xor(data[, z[1]], data[, z[2]]))))
  }))
  return(h_d)
}

hamm_dist_min(data = A)
# A1 B1 C1 
# 2  2  2

df$Hamming <- hamm_dist_min(data = A)
df
#   ID Triplicate Hamming
# 1 A1         T1       2
# 2 B1         T1       2
# 3 C1         T1       2
```

[Youtube example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P02mJhS9qQ4):

```
df1 <- matrix( c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0), ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
colnames(df1) <- LETTERS[1:2]
hamm_dist_min(data = df1)
# A B 
# 3 3
```

---

**EDIT:**
Based on the new dataset added in the question.

Note: If there is only one column for a sample type, then 0 is taken as the hamming distance, because we need at least 2 columns to compute hamming distance. Look at T71 in the triplicate column of `df`. Instead of the value 0, you can return `NA` which means `Not Available`

```
load("Hamming.RData")

# setup unique colnames pattern
col_list <- unique(unlist(lapply( colnames(A), function(x){
  substr(x = x, start = 1, stop = nchar(x) - 1)
} )
))

# get hamming distance
my_results <- lapply( col_list, function(x){
  cols_x <- grep(x, colnames(A) )
  if(length(cols_x) == 1 ){  # return 0 for one column
    return( setNames( object = rep( 0, length(cols_x)), nm = colnames(A)[cols_x]))
  } else{ # return minimum of hamming distance
    return(hamm_dist_min(data = A[, cols_x]))
  }
})

# get triplicate id
triplicate <- paste0( "T", rep(seq_along(my_results), 
                               lengths(my_results)))

# final data
my_results <- unlist(my_results)
df <- data.frame( SampleID = names( my_results ),
                  Hamming = my_results,
                  Triplicate = triplicate,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

head(df)
#                        SampleID Hamming Triplicate
# Affy22_MDA_1       Affy22_MDA_1       2         T1
# Affy22_MDA_2       Affy22_MDA_2       2         T1
# Affy22_MDA_3       Affy22_MDA_3       3         T1
# GutRef001_MDA_1 GutRef001_MDA_1       4         T2
# GutRef001_MDA_2 GutRef001_MDA_2       4         T2
# GutRef001_MDA_3 GutRef001_MDA_3       6         T2
```

Comment: Hi! I like this answer, it gave me a per sample Hamming distance. However for any sample, the solution does not give Hamming distance with respect to what? It compares with all columns in the matrix. However, I want to restrict it to calculate minimum Hamming distance between '`Triplicate` samples mentioned in `df` i.e I want min Hamming distance for A1, B1, C1 belonging to same Triplicate T1. If I have another  set of samples A1, B1, C1 belonging to T2, the minimum for these should be calculated separately. Any ideas how to group and calculate your answer for a `Triplicate` variable.Thanks!

Comment: you can pass selected data to the function. For example: `hamm_dist_min(data = A[, 1:3])`. You have the flexibility to change the number of columns. To find the column names use `colnames(A)`

Comment: Thanks, I have 85 triplicates, hence I was wondering if there was a way to apply the function to a vector of triplicates (where it somehow groups by the `Triplicate` number) and then `rbind` the results?

Comment: create a list of triplicates with column names `col_list <- list(c("A1", "B1", "C1"), c("A2", "B2", "C2"), c("A3", "B3", "C3"), c("A4", "B4", "C4")` and use `lapply(col_list, function(x) {hamm_dist_min(data = df[, x]) } )` and rbind the results from it `do.call('rbind', myresults)`. I think using `sapply` instead of `lapply` might avoid the rbind step. I did not test it.

Comment: Hi, I have added the original data I am working with in the question. If you can provide some suggestions on how to group results by triplicates that will be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: If you want to work strictly with triplicate samples only, then change the condition from `length(cols_x) == 1` to `length(cols_x) != 3` and return `0` or `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a way to calculate the Hamming distance for each pair of columns. I'm not sure how you want to deal with cases where the distances between pairs of columns are the same. Here I just select the first column alphabetically among all columns with same Hamming distance from a given reference column.

```
library(e1071)  # For the hamming.distance function
library(tidyverse)

# Get Hamming distance for all pairs of columns in matrix A. 
hd = combn(colnames(A), 2, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
  map_df(function(col) data.frame(col1=col[1], col2=col[2], 
                                  Hamming=hamming.distance(A[,col[1]], A[, col[2]]))) %>% 
  # For a given column, keep only the shortest Hamming distance
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  arrange(Hamming, col2) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  # Add a column to mark which Hamming distance pair we kept
  mutate(pair = paste0(col1, "_", col2))

hd
```

> ```
>    col1  col2 Hamming  pair
> 1    A1    B1       2 A1_B1
> 2    B1    C1       2 B1_C1
> ```

Now join the Hamming distance values to the appropriate `ID`. First, we stack `col1` and `col2` from `hd` and remove repeated ID values, then we join the result to `df`.

```
df = df %>% left_join(
  bind_rows(hd %>% select(col1, Hamming, pair),
            hd %>% select(col1=col2, Hamming, pair)) %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(col1)),
  by=c("ID"="col1")
)
```

> ```
>   ID Triplicate Hamming  pair
> 1 A1         T1       2 A1_B1
> 2 B1         T1       2 B1_C1
> 3 C1         T1       2 B1_C1
> ```

Comment: Hi, you answer works for me, except that `col1` and `col2` in `hd` should belong to the same `Triplicate`. Right now I am getting hamming_distance pairs from different triplicates because that is the minimum distance. I tried to add this to your code in  `group_by(c(df$Triplicate, col1)) %>%` but it did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some sample data (both matrix `A` and data frame `df`) that represent what the data look like when there are multiple values of triplicate?

Comment: Hi, I just added a link to the exact `A` and `df` data I am working with in the question. Please let me know your suggestions! Thanks!